# Variable won't echo in string

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo the variable `$theurl` inside of `$image_all` but it's not working.

```
$theurl = OF_DIRECTORY;
$image_all =  $theurl.$image_path;
```

This should be simple, right? It's only showing what `$image_path` equals, even though it will echo `$theurl` if I simply do `<?php echo $theurl; ?>`.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no mistake in this code, which means the problem is something you're not showing us.

Comment: You're gonna need to give us more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets make a very very simple example:

```
define(OF_DIRECTORY, 'blabla/test/');

$image_path = 'file.php';

$theurl = OF_DIRECTORY;
$image_all =  $theurl.$image_path;

echo $image_all;
```

Works great by the way! However, why use the $theurl at all? Why not `$image_all =  OF_DIRECTORY . $image_path;`. You need provide us more information or code, but as far as your specifications goes, everything should be OKAY.